# Coordinating tasks using hazel cast lock

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am trying to coordinate the tasks between two nodes using Hazelcast and 
trying to solve this using ILock.

If I create lock using string constant as shown below, do I get the same lock object on two nodes?

```
ILock lock = hazelCastInstance.getLock(STRING_CONSTANT)
lock.tryLock();
```

Is there any better approach to solve this? I have a scenario where task on one node has to wait till the completion of another task on another node.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

According to [the documentation](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.4/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/HazelcastInstance.html):

> Returns the distributed lock instance for the specified key object.

As for the scenario you're describing, I would usually try not to resort to locking mechanisms, and instead use some notification mechanism instead (such as a message broker).

Comment: Yes - definitely prefer event driven over lock driven.